# How do I add https to yarn run?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, deeplearn.js, tensorflow.js

I am trying to run a yarn server with

```
$ yarn run start --https
```

which starts a server, but with http not https.  The --https option works for another project that I was working on, but not this one.  I was wondering if I need to set something in package.json as well to enable https.  For reference, this is the github project that I cloned and am using: https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachable-machine-boilerplate.

Comment: Try with `--ssl`

Comment: thanks, that worked.  feel free to make this an answer.  And maybe add a little explanation of why --ssl works and --https does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boilerplate uses a development server [`budo`](https://github.com/mattdesl/budo), so `yarn start` essentially runs `budo dist`. You can still pass options to it.

`budo` has no `https` option, but it does have an `--ssl` option for this purpose.

```
yarn start --ssl
```

Comment: It creates an https server that I can use from localhost.  But if I go to my local IP location, it refuses the connection.  Again, I don't really understand why since it worked in another project.

Comment: You may look into using a tool like ngrok if you need to access from outside of localhost

Answer (score 5):

Explained on [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/):

```
    HTTPS=true npm start
```

or set it on scripts section of your package.json:

```
    {
      "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I will answer because any of these answers don't work for me!
Its all copied of the internet, but doesn't works fine!

To run in HTTPS your react app follow the guide below:

First you don't need to put `HTTPS=true` in "start" tag, instead, you need in your VS Code terminal, for example, put `set HTTPS=true`

so, yarn start and it will run on https

This is the output running with https
[image: this is the output running with https]

Setting on "start" script tag occurs an error like "HTTPS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, so, I followed this way.

After that I installed my certificate generated with mkcert tool

Answer (score 0):

While @Explosion Pills answer did create an SSL connection for localhost, there was a problem using my local IP.  It turned out that I should have been using `budo` directly instead of `yarn`.  I remedied this with:

```
npm install budo -g
```

And then running this to create the https server:

```
budo main.js --ssl
```

Hopefully my admission of naiveness can discretely help someone in the future!